# How to access new attribute types in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

It appears we can create arbitrary new attributes in blender 2.9:

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Attribute.html

This is a great new feature, but I can't figure out how to access these attributes in a render.  For instance, if I create a new 'VERTEX' attribute of type 'FLOAT_VECTOR' and assign some colour values to it, and then reference that attribute in an attribute node and pipe it into the base colour of a shader, I just get black.

Has anyone figured this out?  Is it maybe simply not implemented yet?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/layers/passes_aov.html https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/output/aov.html https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/layers/passes.html

Comment: Thanks for that, Duarte, good to know about AOVs in cycles, didn't know that was a thing!  But my question is about the new attributes in 2.9, and how to make them visible to the renderer.